# htaccess redirect API to sub folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My document root (/var/www/html/) looks like this:

```
app/
    client/
        index.html

    server/
        api/
            user/
                get.php
        classes/
        models/
```

When the user navigates to any URL on my website that does NOT start with `api/`, they should load the index.html file inside of `client`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ^ app/client/index.html [QSA,L]
```

That code works correctly.

However, when the URL starts with `api/`, I want to direct the URL to the api folder under `server/`.

For instance, `www.website.com/user` would load the index.html file.
Whereas `www.website.com/api/user/get.php` would load `www.website.com/server/api/user/get.php`.

I know that I would need a special condition for `api/` before my current condition.

`RewriteRule ^api app/server/api [L]`

That rule works when using `www.website.com/api`, but it does not work when there are slashes after `api/`. `www.website.com/api` -> `www.website.com/app/server/api`, `www.website.com/api/test` -> `www.website.com/var/www/html/test`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api(/.*)?$ app/server/api$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ^ app/client/index.html [L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.